# How to save an openssl key/iv to a file and then recover it?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt a file, save the key/iv to a file, then recover the key/iv from the file.

For some reason, after I read the file, the data has changed in some way that I cannot fathom.

See below for a MWE:

```rb
require 'openssl'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm')
cipher.encrypt
original = cipher.random_key
File.open("foo", "w") {|f| f.write(original) }
readfromfile = File.read("foo")
if readfromfile != original
  puts "The information has changed, but why?"
end
```

I am expecting the data to be unchanged after I read it from file, but ruby always returns them as different.

When I print original and readfromfile they always look identical. When I compare original and cat of the file they look identical.

The class of the data both return string.

If I save any other string into the file and read it back it stays the same.

I get the same result whether I generate a key or iv.

What is happening?

Secondary question: is there a way in ruby to run a comparison that returns *what* the difference is? Something like diff?

Comment: Looks like a UTF-8 encoding issue because they are not the same on my system: `\r\xBF\x11S...` vs `r\xBF\u0011S...`. Not sure beyond that at a glance.

Comment: Looks like that could be right, exploring now. Could you tell me, what are you using to inspect it that's giving you the above result?

Comment: `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin19]` on macOS with [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/) instead of IRB. I copied and pasted your code into pry then I just typed `original` and `readfromfile` to see the output of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could not get to the bottom of why the data was changing, but I solved the problem by encoding the iv and key to base64 (using this gem: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html), before saving it to file, and then decoding it after reading it from file.